# Symfony 2 - What to do before going live?

Tags: symfony, configuration, production

Until now, I've been writing Symfony 2 applications and never was responsible for launches. So I've only called Smyfony 2 over `app_dev.php` and only used a development configuration. Now I have to take care of a Symfony 2 launch, what do consider before going live?

- Where can I set different configurations (DB connection, etc.) for different environments and how can I invoke them?
- How can I make sure the application can't be called via `app_dev.php` on the live server?
- And of cure any other tips on what to keep a eye on while pushing a Symfony 2 application live.

Comment: This relates to the 1.x series, but offers some good advice nonetheless: http://www.symfony-check.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we have documented this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html That article just answers the first and third question, the answer on the second question:

> How can I make sure the application can't be called via app_dev.php on the live server?

You should point the root directory of you website to the `web` directory. For instance, if you site lives in:

```
mysite.com/
    public_html/
        ... your site files/directories
```

You should make it like this:

```
mysite.com/
    app/
        ...
    src/
        ...
    vendor/
        ...
    public_html/ <--- this is the old web directory
        ...
        app.php
```

You can read how to change the `web` directory in `public_html` into the documentation too: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html

The reason to do this is to secure all your application code. The user just can't access all `app/.`, `vendor/.` and `src/.` files and so it can't read the configuration and can't read the parameters.

At last, you can change `app.php` to `index.php` to get urls like `mysite.com/app.php/blog/foobar`. But it is better to create a simple HTACCESS mod_rewrite rule to send all requests to `app.php`, so you can access the page with `mysite.com/blog/foobar`.

`.htaccess` in the root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ app.php$1
```

Answer (score 0):

> Where can I set different configurations (DB connection, etc.) for different environments and how can I invoke them?

if you haven't changed too much your project, your config files are under app/config

> How can I make sure the application can't be called via app_dev.php on the live server?

Same, if you haven't change to much the project, the only thing you need to care about is make sure your web server runs the website from /web (the .htaccess does the rest)

> And of cure any other tips on what to keep a eye on while pushing a Symfony 2 application live.

You can keep an eye on the log files in app/logs